# Manager isn't accessible

Tags: django, django-views

[image: Manager error]

**** view in the model*****

```
class detail(DetailView):
    model = Requisicao
    context_object_name = 'requisicao'
    template_name = 'detail.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
    


 
class itemManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(itemManager, self).get_queryset()
```

---

First of all, thank you for your time and help.

I'm trying to bring the items from this queryset but it's showing this error in my browser.

I would like to know how to solve it.

Comment: That does not make much sense: you use a `DetailView`, so it passes a *single* object to the template.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite odd to do this in a `DetailView`: a `DetailView` is used to work with a *single* object, not a list of these objects. But based on the error, you want to render some sort of table of the model objects.

In that case a `ListView` is more appropriate, with:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView


class RequisicaoListView(ListView):
    model = Requisicao
    context_object_name = 'requisicao'
    template_name = 'list.html'
```

and enumerate over the items with:

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    <!-- … -->
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `…View` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `RequisicaoListView`, instead of <s>`detail`</s>.

---

> **Note**: It might be worth to take a look at [**`django-tables2`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2) to render tables in an effective way.